# Why does table of contents start from 0.1, not 1?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have created this table of contents and from what you can see, it starts from 0.1, not 1.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tab.}
\setlist{leftmargin=2cm}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
    
\begin{document}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{2}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Section}
Dummy text
\subsection{Subsection}
Dummy text

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Why it happens and how can I fix it and make it start from 1?

Comment: Do you use a documentclass which uses `\chapter` as highest sectioning level?

Comment: Now you know why we always as for full minimal examples and not sniplets like this, Like Sam says you're probably using a class which uses `\chapter` as the primary sectional division, but and thus section numbering goes `<chapter>.<section>` as there are no chapters the chapter counter is zero.

Comment: @dokichan Thanks for your edit! Either switch to `article` class if you want sections as highest element or use chapters instead.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you very much for answer, it worked. Write, please, this comment as answer, so I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: You can sitll use report with `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` (although I can't think of a good reason for doing so).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `report` document class uses `chapter` as highest sectioning level. You can solve in a number of ways, e.g.

- switch to a class like `article` which uses sections as top level element
- use `\chapter` instead of `\section` in your code